# Explain return to me when its nested

Tags: javascript, return

I am pretty new to javascript and doing a course.I understand the return principle but when its nested in for example a nested for loop i get really confused.Would anyone mind to explain it to me?here is nothing nested but I got some example-code:

```js
let generatePlayerBoard = (numberOfRows,numberOfColumns)=>{
  const board = [];
  for (var rowIndex = 0;  rowIndex < numberOfRows.length;  rowIndex++) {
    const row = [];
    for (var columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < numberOfColumns.length; columnIndex++) {
      row.push(' ');
    }
    board.push(row);
  }
  return board;
};
  
  
  console.log(generatePlayerBoard(2,3));
```

Thank you already for the help :D

Comment: There's nothing nested anywhere in the code you posted. If you properly indent your code, you'll be able to more easily see the execution flow.

Comment: `return` simply exits the function and returns the specified value. If it's inside a `for` loop, it will stop the loop when it's executed and end the function. But there's nothing like that in the example code you posted, are you sure that's what you had the question about?

Comment: `numberOfRows.length` should just be `numberOfRows`, and same for `numberOfColumns`.

Comment: Example code does not do us any good if it does not show what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

The basics of nested returns is that a function can only return a value once, so once a function reaches its first return statement it ends the function.

Here's an example:

```
function hello () {
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if(i > 10) {
            return 'Since i is never > 10 Im never reached so I never get to return anything'
        } else {
            return 'Hello!'
        }
        return 'The else statements returns before Im reached'
    }
    return 'Im never reached';
}

alert(hello());
```

Run that little script and you'll get an alert that says 'Hello!'

As mentioned before, in your script the return isn't nested, it's just run after all your other code has run.

Nesting is when you e.g. run:

```
if(1 < 2) {
if(2 < 3) {
// This second if is called a nested if because it's run inside another
// if statement
}
}

if(1 < 2 && 2 < 3) {
// This is also a form of nested if because it has the same effect as running
// the code above
}
```